# Determining wheter a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n<1$, $a_n \to 1$ and where $a_{2n}>a_{2n+1}$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis

> Give an example of a sequence $a_n$ such that $a_n<1$, $a_n \to 1$ and where $a_{2n}>a_{2n+1}$.

I’ve tried to construct this by using terms like $\frac{1}{n}$, but I seem to be having a tradeoff with the sequence convering to $1$ and being strictly less than $1$. $a_n = 1+ (-\frac{1}{n})^n$ has two other properties, but for any even $n$ this sequence is greater than $1$. Does such a sequence exist?

Comment: Think of a “zigzag” curve approaching the value one. Then try to express that as a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct arbitrarily many sequences like this as follows:

1. Take $b_n \rightarrow 1$ such that $b_n < 1$.
2. Take $c_n \rightarrow 0$ such that $c_n > 0$.
3. Set $a_{2n} = b_n$, $a_{2n+1} = b_n - c_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$a_{2n} = 1 - \frac{1}{100n}$, $a_{2n+1} = 1 - \frac{100}n$. Then $a_{2n} \to 1$ and  $a_{2n+1} \to 1$ and hence $a_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Define $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ so that

$$a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}\text{ if }n\text{ is odd and }1-\frac{1}{n^2}\text{ if }n\text{ is even}$$

$a_n<1$ follows from the fact that $1/n>0$ and $1/n^2>0$ for every $n\geq 1$. $a_n\to 1$ follows from

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}=1$$

Finally, we have $a_{2n}>a_{2n+1}$ because

$$\frac{1}{n^2}<\frac{1}{n}\text{ for every }n>1$$